# How to create a DateTime nicely which is today at 23:00

Tags: c#

I want a DateTime variable which is today (any given time of the day) at 23:00.

There has simply got to be a cleaner way to do this because this reminds me too much of good ol' ASP.Classic...

```
var startDate = DateTime.Parse(DateTime.Now.ToShortDateString() + " 23:00:00");
```

Anyone?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

```
var eleven = DateTime.Today.AddHours(23);
```

Comment: `DateTime.Today.AddHours(23)`

Comment: @ck probably because of the lead time between reading the question and clicking on "post your answer". We wouldn't have this problem with Google Wave ;)

Comment: worst thing is when an identical answer posted a few minutes behind yours is accepted as the answer to the question, what's all that about?

Comment: Normally StackOverflow pops up a message if someone posted an answer in the time I was reading the question or writing an answer. Unfortunately this seems to not work when using multiple windows/tabs. This is why I posted the same answer(ish) :(

Comment: @Ian: can't count the number of times this has happened to me.  (or better yet someone posts the same answer as you a few mins later - they read yours - and then add one more sentence to make it a "better" answer.)

Answer (score 2):

```
var elevenPM = DateTime.Today.AddHours(23);
```

Comment: DateTime.Today.AddHours (23), is prettier. :)

Answer (score 1):

```
var dt = DateTime.Now.Date + TimeSpan.FromHours(23);
```

Answer (score 0):

A clean Way is:

```
DateTime myTime = DateTime.Now.Date.AddHours(23);
```

Another Way is:

```
DateTime myTime = DateTime.Now.Date + new TimeSpan("23","0","0");
```

Comment: afaik the parameters for TimeSpan are integers so the "" are wrong there, not sure though

Comment: +1 just to counteract the -1 because this is a totally legitimate answer, extraneous quotation marks in the `TimeSpan` constructor aside (`DateTime.Now.Date` will return the same result as `DateTime.Today`, and that answer got 17 upvotes).